# Cisco ASA vague error

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I'm getting a very vague error from my cisco ASA that connects our VPN to a branch office running a cisco router. I was hoping some one could give me some incite into how I could possibly pull more information from this. There hasn't been any degradation of service and the VPN tunnel hasn't dropped. Just this error that started popping up multiple times daily and I've been tasked to find out why. Already called cisco and they were no help. Below is the error and any help would be appreciated.

<163>Aug 07 2014 11:01:39: %ASA-3-752015: Tunnel Manager has failed to establish an L2L SA.  All configured IKE versions failed to establish the tunnel. Map Tag= vpn.  Map Sequence Number = 1.

Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 9.1(3)
Device Manager Version 7.1(5)100

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a compatibility issue between 9.1 and an older version of ASA software.
Matching them up should be the easiest solution.

Comment: Nope no answer as of yet. Cisco said if I simplify my ACL list it might help. They also checked the versions when I was on the phone with them and said they were fine. Claimed it was a general error and should be ignored but nothing changed when we started to get the error so we wanted to get it figured out.